# Increasing cubic function $f(x)$ in $3 < x < 4$, $f(2) = 8$ and $f(-4) = -16$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, cubics

How do we solve the following problem?

> A function $f(x)$ is a cubic function which is increasing at interval $3 < x < 4$. If $f(2) = 8$ and $f(-4) = -16$, find the equation of function!*

I try to solve it as 3 variable equation by assuming that $f'(x)$ is $0$ at $3$ and $4$. But I don't know how to put the fact that the function is increasing at $3 < x < 4$ to something that I can solve using algbera. Can somebody help explain this problem to me?

Comment: There is no reason to assume $f'(3)=f'(4)=0$.  You want $f'(x) \gt 0$ on $(3,4)$ but it could be positive at $3,4$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of freedom

$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$

If we set $b = 0$ and $a,c > 0$

Then $f(x)$ will be increasing for all $x$

We still have 3 unknowns and 2 conditions to solve for, meaning we still have freedom.  We can assign a value to $a$ that is convenient and solve for $c, d$

let $a = \frac 14$

$f(x) = \frac 14 x^3 + c(x+4)$

Now $f(x)$ will go through the point $(-4,-16)$

And we just need to solve for $c$

$f(x) = \frac 14 x^3 + x+4$

And this is just one of many equations you could choose.

Update:

$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d\\
f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx+c > 0$

When $x\in [3,4]$

Either $a > 0$ and $f'(x)$ has no real roots.
or $a>0$ and both roots are to the left of $3$, or both roots are to the right of $4$

or $a<0$ and [3,4] is inside the roots.

$x = \frac {b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 3ac}}{3}$

My short-cut was to assume $a>0$ and $b = 0$ thus $f'(x)$ has no real roots and $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

If you want to solve for one of the other cases, you are welcome to, but you are asking for more work...

Comment: thank you so much for the quick answer!
But is it possible to solve it using derivative in calculus? I found this problem while reading in maths textbook in the chapter of derivative. so I thought it has some connection with first derivate of  cubic function?

Comment: A good approach.

Comment: @MichaelChen  I have added a little bit more detail on the thought process.

Comment: Wow, i never know mathematics could be solved using such approach. Thank you for your help, appreciate it! One last question, you say that we can use any value of a that is convenient to us. But when I use a= 1, I got negative value for c. We have put a condition that a,c>0 .  is there a way to find the forbidden value for 'a' based on a,c>0 constraint?

Comment: Never mind, i found the forbidden value already. Thankyou very much!